# Framework for communicating between iOS and MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I'm looking to build a pair of apps that work in a similar way to iTunes and the Remote app for iOS... Is there a framework for connecting iOS and MacOS over wifi?

Bluetooth is something I'd like to avoid and there's no need for a web service, I'm just looking to control my Mac app remotely from the phone.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CoreBluetooth (Bluetooth Low-Energy) doesn't need pairing. You could also use MultiPeerConnectivity I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Id say the most ideal way to accomplish this is via the Bonjour protocol.

Here is a great article on the subject, http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-networking-and-bonjour-on-iphone/.

Good thing with using Bonjour in iOS is it also works via Bluetooth.

Hope this helps !

here is an example project  which exchange the data between iphone and iMAC with WiFi connectivity.

https://github.com/boobalaninfo/Bonjour-iOS-MAC-Apps

Use bonjour to search for devices. Then use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket) to send and receive data. It works like a charm.

Little info about AsyncSock:

> GCDAsyncSocket and AsyncSocket are TCP/IP socket networking libraries.
>   Here are the key features available in both:
>
> Native objective-c, fully self-contained in one class. No need to muck
>   around with sockets or streams. This class handles everything for you.
>
> Full delegate support Errors, connections, read completions, write
>   completions, progress, and disconnections all result in a call to your
>   delegate method.
>
> Queued non-blocking reads and writes, with optional timeouts. You tell
>   it what to read or write, and it handles everything for you. Queueing,
>   buffering, and searching for termination sequences within the stream -
>   all handled for you automatically.
>
> Automatic socket acceptance. Spin up a server socket, tell it to
>   accept connections, and it will call you with new instances of itself
>   for each connection.
>
> Support for TCP streams over IPv4 and IPv6. Automatically connect to
>   IPv4 or IPv6 hosts. Automatically accept incoming connections over
>   both IPv4 and IPv6 with a single instance of this class. No more
>   worrying about multiple sockets.
>
> Support for TLS / SSL Secure your socket with ease using just a single
>   method call. Available for both client and server sockets.